Problem with Controller_manager waiting for service /controller_manager/list_controllers to become available.... failed
i got a problem with "Controller_manager" and i tried everything but i could not find out why it does not work i am trying to simulate a quaderocopter on Gazebo. the only thing i need now to be able to controle it with cmd or any other way. the main task for me to make it move now :( can someone help me out ?

ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args -r
/cmd_vel:=^cmd_vel

Logs:


[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.864534726] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> Loading joint: base_to_b1 [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.865058906]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: State: [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.865304843] [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.865550580] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Command:
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.865997148] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> velocity [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.866252286]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b2 [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.866493223] [gazebo_ros2_control]: State: [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.866944491] [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.867187428] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> Command: [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.867424663]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.867673401] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint:
> base_to_b3 [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.868077262]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: State: [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.868315498] [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.868553334] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Command:
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.868939592] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> velocity [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.869187030]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: base_to_b4 [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.869427566] [gazebo_ros2_control]: State: [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.869667002] [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.870072263] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> Command: [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.870313200]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: velocity [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.870915391] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware
> 'GazeboSystem' [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.871324953]
> [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware
> 'GazeboSystem' [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.871635000]
> [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSystem' [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.871980752] [resource_manager]: Successful
> 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSystem' [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298008.872127674] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware
> 'GazeboSystem' [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.872273896]
> [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298008.872633651] [gazebo_ros2_control]:
> Loading controller_manager [gzserver-2] [WARN] [1726298008.978654374]
> [gazebo_ros2_control]: Desired controller update period (0.02 s) is
> slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s). [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298008.979865557] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded
> gazebo_ros2_control. [INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid
> [38531] [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298010.995336568]
> [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
> [spawner-7] [INFO] [1726298011.293255595]
> [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298011.304390778] [controller_manager]:
> Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster' [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298011.307354325] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or
> 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will
> be published [spawner-7] [INFO] [1726298011.404351785]
> [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated
> joint_state_broadcaster [INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished
> cleanly [pid 38531] [gzclient-3] context mismatch in
> svga_surface_destroy [gzclient-3] context mismatch in
> svga_surface_destroy [INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid
> [38546] [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298017.129551568]
> [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'velocity_controller'
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1726298017.465302613]
> [spawner_velocity_controller]: Loaded velocity_controller [gzserver-2]
> [INFO] [1726298017.484964485] [controller_manager]: Configuring
> controller 'velocity_controller' [gzserver-2] [INFO]
> [1726298017.499302851] [velocity_controller]: configure successful
> [gzserver-2] [INFO] [1726298017.561079988] [velocity_controller]:
> activate successful [spawner-8] [INFO] [1726298017.607934670]
> [spawner_velocity_controller]: Configured and activated
> velocity_controller [INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly
> [pid 38546]

launch_sim.launch.py:
 import os
 from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
 from launch import LaunchDescription
 from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, 
 DeclareLaunchArgument, 
 TimerAction
 from launch.launch_description_sources import 
 PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
 from launch_ros.actions import Node
 from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

def generate_launch_description():
package_name = 'my_bot'

rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'launch', 'rsp.launch.py'
    )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
)

gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py'
    )]),
)

spawn_entity = Node(
    package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', '-entity', 'my_bot'],
    output='screen'
)

joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"],
    output="screen"
)

velocity_controller_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["velocity_controller"],
    output="screen"
)

use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

joy_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_bot'), 'config', 'joystick.yaml')

joy_node = Node(
    package='joy',
    executable='joy_node',
    parameters=[joy_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
)

teleop_node = Node(
    package='teleop_twist_joy',
    executable='teleop_node',
    name='teleop_node',
    parameters=[joy_params, {'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
    remappings=[('/cmd_vel','/cmd_vel')]
)

return LaunchDescription([
    rsp,
    gazebo,
    spawn_entity,

    TimerAction(
        period=5.0,
        actions=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner]
    ),
    TimerAction(
        period=10.0,
        actions=[velocity_controller_spawner]
    ),
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_sim_time',
        default_value='false',
        description='Use sim time if true',
    ),
    joy_node,
    teleop_node,
])

drone.urdf.xacro:
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
  <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
  <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
  <parameters>/home/alba/dev_ws/src/my_bot/config/rotor_controller.yaml</parameters>
</plugin>
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
<hardware>
    <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
</hardware>

<joint name="base_to_b1">
    <command_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>
<joint name="base_to_b2">
    <command_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>
<joint name="base_to_b3">
    <command_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>
<joint name="base_to_b4">
    <command_interface name="velocity"/>
    <state_interface name="velocity"/>
</joint>
</ros2_control>

rotor_controller.yaml:
controller_manager:
    ros__parameters:
      update_rate: 50
      joint_state_broadcaster:
       type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
      velocity_controller:
       type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
       
velocity_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - base_to_b1
      - base_to_b2
      - base_to_b3
      - base_to_b4

joystick.yaml:
joy_node:
  ros__parameters:
    device_id: 0
    deadzone: 0.05
    autorepeat_rate: 20.0

teleop_node:
  ros__parameters:
    axis_linear:
      z: 4
      x: 1
      y: 3
    scale_linear:
      z: 2.0
      x: 5.0
      y: 5.0
    scale_linear_turbo:
      z: 5.0
      x: 10.0
      y: 10.0
    axis_angular:
      yaw: 0
    scale_angular:
      yaw: 5.0
    scale_angular_turbo: 
      yaw: 10.0
    enable_turbo_button: 1
    require_enable_button: false


i updated my code up there and my question. i am new here as you can see. so sorry for that

can you please add the full log from gazebo? The spawners can't find the CM, which is just the consequence of an earlier issue.

hi! thx for answering now. What do you mean with the log from gazebo ?.
my english is not that good

exactly what you have posted above. I don't see any evidence that gazebo_ros2_control.was launched at all. which ROS distro are you using? does gazebo start and you see your robot?

i am using humble 22.04 on VMware
Gazebo is working and i can see the robot (a drone)
the only thing is missing that i can not controll it. i want to be able to move it with cmd command

and just to make sure i am using Ros2 with Gazebo classic.

You don't need to launch the ros2_control_node if you are using gazebo_ros2_control. Please have a look on the demos or gazebo_ros2_control_demos how to setup your project.

well i realise i did not need it so i did some changes and i could fix the errors but i still cant move my robot, tbh i dont know anymore what i have to do. so i hope someone can help me out: i tried to remapping
i updated my code you might find somthing out better than me. your answer helped me out to fix the errors, thx!
